# What is the maximum size of file that Jackson Csv to Json library can handle?

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, out-of-memory

I am using Jackson to convert a csv file to json. However I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Too many entries: expected at most 71 (value #71 (0 chars) "")
 at [Source: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader@5f83bcb8; line: 149, column: 1153]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1487)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:518)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._handleNextEntryExpectEOL(CsvParser.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._handleNextEntry(CsvParser.java:629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser.nextToken(CsvParser.java:472)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.nextValue(MappingIterator.java:188)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.readAll(MappingIterator.java:226)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.readAll(MappingIterator.java:212)
    at CsvToJsonParser.readObjectsFromCsv(CsvToJsonParser.java:47)
    at CsvToJsonParser.convertCsvToJson(CsvToJsonParser.java:36)
    at MainParser.main(MainParser.java:16)
```

I noticed that I am getting this exception when I have a file with more than ~70 entries. However I want to convert a file with ~60000 entries!!! 
Anybody has an idea what causes the limitation to the Jackson library??

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the error message. Please check what is on  line 149, column: 1153 in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented on misunderstanding wrt error message; but to be precise, error message indicates that there is an extra value on specified row. Looking at additional value (empty String), I am guessing you simply have an extra comma at the end of that line.